# How to do pass insensitive flags to match in one command?

Tags: python

I am doing an case insensitive match against several keys with flags behind compile pattern:

```
def case(string):
    switcher = {
        re.compile('bronze', re.IGNORECASE):10,
        re.compile('carbon', re.IGNORECASE):16,
    }
    for i in switcher.keys():
        if re.match(i, string):
            return switcher[i]
    return "Invalid: " + string
```

Is there a smarter way of passing the flags, so I do not have to specify it in every line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `re.compile` at all, really. `re.match` and friends internally cache the last-used regexp patterns anyway.

Here, `switcher` has been refactored out of the `case` function so it doesn't get recomputed on each invocation; in addition, we're using `dict.items()` to get both the pattern and the value simultaneously.

```
switcher = {
    'bronze': 10,
    'carbon': 16,
}

def case(string):
    for pattern, value in switcher.items():
        if re.match(pattern, string, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
            return value
    return "Invalid: " + string
```

Based on your example, though, it's not clear if you need regexps at all, or if you just need case-insensitive substring matching, in which case it will be cheaper computationally to lower-case your test string, then just use `if str1 in str2`, like this (assuming the same `switcher` dict as in the previous example.)

```
def case_no_re(string):
    l_string = string.lower()
    for pattern, value in switcher.items():
        if pattern in l_string:
            return value
    return "Invalid: " + string
```

Comment: Thank you, the first example workes in my case excellent as I do need the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can factor it to a local function (or even not local, if it's of wider interest to your module/application).

```
def case(string):
    def ire(pattern):
        return re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)

    switcher = {
        ire('bronze'):10,
        ire('carbon'):16,
    }
```

By the way, if you are not actually exploiting the fast lookup by key of the `dict` but you are only iterating over it, a better data structure for `switcher` would be a plain list of tuples `(regexp, value)`.